# What are some great web based interfaces that you use on a day to day basis?

Tags: user-interface

I definitely appreciate a good interface and as a developer, I try to create them for my users.  But appreciating a good interface and designing one are a different thing.  I'm looking for good interfaces (such as IMHO StackOverflow, Gmail) as examples of good UI from which I can model my own UI's.

Comment: You should make this community wiki as it doesn't have a single right answer

Comment: I like this question.   I think it's been asked before, but I like it.

Comment: @Gortok mind posting a link as an answer? I would like to read the previous results.

Answer (score 6):

I personally think that [Netflix](http://www.netflix.com/) has an excellent web UI. Responsive, easy to navigate. Not mutch [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) going on, but I find it very comfortable.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty much anything by google, really. They're all very simple and to the point, focusing on usability.

Comment: Hahahaha. I want to disagree with you so badly, but can't come up with examples. +1 ;-)

Comment: I can give you an example - the GSA xsl textarea.  We paid how much for.. THIS!?

Comment: Why wasn't this wiki? User wants Rep?

Comment: @Gortok, we've all enjoyed a few rep boosts now and then. Neither you nor I are innocent. Makes up for all those other posts that get 0 attention.

Comment: This question wasn't a CW when I answered it, so I didn't make my answer a wiki either. It now is, so it's been changed. Please don't assume I'm rep-whoring without consulting the history of this question.

Answer (score 3):

You should get yourself a copy of both [Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758) and [The Non-Designer's Design Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321534042) for your base knowledge/insight.

From there, it's much easier for you to dissect and analyze the layouts you already know and like, and recreate them for your own amusement.

*edit:* To mitigate misunderstanding, the point I'm trying to make is that you probably don't need as many good examples of nice layouts, if you know what to look for. For example, I can be shown a thousand *haute couture* dresses, and I still couldn't make one myself, because I don't know what to look for.

Comment: But I think he was asking *specific* examples of web sites done right. We all know the standard Joel response. +1 'cause those books are great.

Comment: The point I was trying to make that he don't need as many examples as he thinks he needs, once he knows what to look for. I should clarify myself.

Answer (score 3):

My favorites

- Stack Overflow: This is a WIKI so it's not a rep point grab.  I just really love the interface on this site.  Been to too many crappy Q/A sites
- Google Reader
- MSDN: It's gotten a ton better in recent years and is a great way to grab little esoteric details about various APIs

Comment: MSDN's biggest problem is that their search is absolutely horrible.  I can never find the page I want.  If I use google to search MSDN, I almost always find exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: The tree navigation is crazy, and the way pages are organized can get a little hairy outside of the framework docs.

Answer (score 1):

[iStockPhoto.com](http://www.istockphoto.com) it's simple, effective and handles a large amount of information and data without getting bogged down. It also doesn't get in the way of the info you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A good user interface fulfills a specific need of its users effectively.

As an example, [here is a site](http://www.varjocafe.net/?ids=33,37,38,47) ([translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?prev=hp&hl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.varjocafe.net%2F%3Fids%3D33%2C37%2C38%2C47&sl=fi&tl=en)) that I have created for finding out what food is available in the cafeterias of the University of Helsinki. The typical use case is that when a student is hungry, he needs to know what food is available in the neighborhood student cafeterias (which are cheap for students), so that he can choose where to eat and what. He knows where each of those cafeterias is, but does not know what food they have today.

That site shows all the needed information at once. Because the students typically have a couple of cafeterias where they go, they can either bookmark the page with those cafeterias selected, or save the selection as a cookie. After that they can reach their goal without any navigation on the web site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use it on a day-to-day basis, but I'm very impressed with the [Perseus Project](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/) digital library.

[Here's a link to a poem from Catullus' *Carmina*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text.jsp?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0003) in Latin as an example of the interface. Some features that I really like:

- Click on the bar near the top to jump to any poem in the work. Larger chunks of the bar represent larger sections of the work (poems, chapters, however that particular work is logically broken up by the author).
- Click on a Latin word in the poem to bring up a window (be patient; it seems to take a while) with lexicon entries, user voting and statistics on the word form (i.e. what the inflection means in the context of the sentence; it can be ambiguous in Latin) and so forth.
- There are a number of resources down the right column, including various English translations, notes, references, etc. Any of them can be either shown in the right column, or swapped out with whatever is in the main content area in the center.

Answer (score 0):

One of my personal favs: [newspond.com](http://newspond.com)